# How would I query how many customers hit a page even if they weren't customers at the time?

Tags: analytics, keen-io

Say I'm streaming pageview data to keen.io, with a `visitor_id` property. As well as that property, say there's an `is_customer` boolean.

```
pageview = {
  "visitor_id" : "292n0s9f323"
  "is_customer" : true,
  "page" : "https://burningman.org/xyz"
}
```

I know how to count how many of last month's unique visitors hit the /xyz page, and I know how to count how many of those were customers at the time they hit said page… but..

How would I count how many customers hit the /xyz page this month EVEN IF they weren't customers at the time they hit that page?

Answer (score 2):

You'd use a funnel to calculate this retroactively, similar to how you would do ad attribution.

```
var funnel = new Keen.Query("funnel", {
  steps: [
    { // step one counts how many unique customers viewed any pages in the timeframe
      event_collection: "pageview",
      actor_property: "visitor_id",
      timeframe: "this_30_days",
      filters: [
        {
          property_name: "is_customer",
          operator: "eq",
          property_value: true
        }
      ]
    },
    { // step two counts how many of those specific visitors viewed XYZ page
      event_collection: "pageview",
      actor_property: "visitor_id",
      timeframe: "this_30_days",
      filters: [
        {
          property_name: "is_customer",
          operator: "eq",
          property_value: true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
});
```

Response looks like:

```
{
  "result": [
    3034,  // count of unique customers who viewed any page
    24 // count of those customers who at some point viewed XYZ page
  ],
  "steps": // additional metadata...
}
```